# Rails latest content bloc for many controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, each, render

I'm looking for create a latest content bloc for the root page.
List only 4 latests items for the exemple.
I'm understanding how make that for a simple controller, something each do |post|, but I have many controllers.
Blog, post, illustration, etc.
How to regroup the 4 most ressently contents for make the "latest content" block.
Thank you.

EDIT :

Now I have that in my home_controller

```
def index
    @titre = "Accueil"
    @blogs = Blog.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
    @makingofmangas = Makingofmanga.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
    @illustrations = Illustration.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
    @materiels = Materiel.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
end
```

In my index.htlm.erb I want a bloc with only for latest something. No 4 latest blogs, and 4 latest illustrations, etc, but 4 latest of all.

If I do that, I have only the 4 latest blog.

```
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-image"><%= image_tag blog.couverture.url(:hd) %>
<h3 class="card-image-headlineombre"><%= blog.title %></h3>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
<%= link_to 'Lire le billet&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.html_safe, blog, { :class=>"btn btn-raised btn-info" } %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The question is, how to add the rest for making what I want ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
@blogs = Blog.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
```

It must get latest four `Blogs`.

In your controllers action, all your variables with `@` symbol will be visible in view which corresponds to this action. For example if your controller is `page` and action is `index`, it will have `index.html.erb` and in your `page_controller` there will be `def index` method. Inside of this method you can write this:

```
def index
   @blogs = Blog.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
   @posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
   @illustrations = Illustration.order(created_at: :desc).limit(4)
end
```

In your `index.html.erb` view file, you can access to `@blogs`, `@posts` and `@illustrations` variable.

Comment: Thank you. I know that but I want regroup all the controllers contents in the "latest contents" block, not only the blog's contents.

Comment: You want to share data between controllers?

Comment: No. In a render. I need to create a model ? helper ? I'm beginner.

Comment: Ok. Next. I added that in my index.html.erb <% @blogs.each do |blog| %><% atposts.each do |post| %>  But I don't want 4 each but last 4 total.